# How do I convert Dataframe to RDD in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I need to convert data frame to RDD and need to apply some core opertaions on it. 
tried below things. its is converting into list,Row or tuple formats. but some of the core functions or not working on those like .split().

tried below methods:

```
df.rdd.map(list)
```

or

```
df.rdd.map(tuple)
```

or

```
df.rdd
```

sample code i am trying

```
rdd=load_df.rdd.map(list)
conv_rdd= rdd.map(lambda x:x.split(","))
```

need to perform some operations from here on

Answer (score 5):

A data frame is a Data set of `Row` objects. When you run `df.rdd`, the returned value is of type `RDD<Row>`.

Now, `Row` doesn't have a `.split` method. You probably want to run that on a field of the row. So you need to call

```
df.rdd.map(lambda x:x.stringFieldName.split(","))
```

Split must run on a value of the row, not the `Row` object itself.

Comment: what is stringFieldName can you please explain.. is it column name?

Comment: @LUZO Yes, it is the column name.

Comment: in real time i have 1000 + columns...how come i handle those? and some times i need to remove the header too..is there any method that converts my df to rdd itself ?

Comment: To convert a DF to an RDD? What fields do you want to include? Can you share the schema of the data frame. Also, do you want the plain RDD of strings, as if you'd run `sc.textFile`?

Comment: yes i want it as plain RDD of strings...just like sc.textFile. sample schema of dataframe is [col1:int, col2:string, col3:float, col4: date....so on ]

Comment: How did you create it initially then? Maybe it's better to change the DF creation instead of converting each row to text and then concat all of them

Comment: taken data from hive and created dataframe.. mkstring will work here in pyspark?